# Can you run a custom script that affects SQLite storage in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am creating an app that will save data on the local phone memory with `react-native-sqlite-storage`.

I want to make a script that will create a database (if it does not exist), create the necessary tables, and then populate those tables with mock data (basically, a seed script). I plan on adding a script to my `package.json` to seed this data, something like

```
{
    ....
    "scripts": {
        ....
        "seed": "ts-node index.ts"
    }
}
```

Where `index.ts` will contain the necessary seeding script, something like:

```
// import react-native-sqlite-storage
const seedDatabase = () => {
    // Populate the data ...
}
seedDatabase();
```

But I am uncertain if this would work. Will it work? If not, is there a way to seed data?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use this package to create and populate your database https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3
2. then just run this to copy it to your device

```
adb push your_db.db /storage/emulated/0/your_db.db
```

3. In your react native code just use that file https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#importing-a-pre-populated-database